# Angular live search filter on row iterator

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a template in which I have rows, and there are two elements in each row and each element has different classes so I have my Html structure like so (simplified)

```
<div ng-repeat "row in deals">
  <div class="deal-title-left">{{row[0].title}}</div>
  <div class="deal-title-right">{{row[1].title}}</div>
</div>
```

I would like to add a search box feature that will use live search to go through the deal titles. I have tried using the ng-model="search" and adding a search filter into the row div, but how do I apply the model to each individual deal instead of the entire row?

Answer (score 1):

Demo :http://plnkr.co/edit/zGYLPcPHTr1TOSZTIBI2?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.2.21" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
  <div ng-repeat="row in deals | filter :{title:search}">
  <div class="deal-title-left">{{row.title}}</div>

</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.deals = [{
      title: "Cola for free"
    }, {
      title: "Icecream for free"
    }, {
      title: "Tee for free"
    },


  ]
});
```